# AJAX results radio button verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that returns html.  This html includes two radio buttons.  When the page is submitted, I need to verify the ajax results have had a radio selected.  On initial page load, I have no problem, it is when I try to verify ajax results that it fails on the verification.

This is the code I am looking to implement :

```
 $("body").on("click", "address_type", function submitPage(event) { 
  var selectedVal = "";
  var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='address_type']:checked");
  if (selected.length > 0) {
    selectedVal = selected.val();
  }else{
    alert('Check address type');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

The radio I am looking to verify (returned by ajax):

```
<label class="container">Radio No
<input name="address_type" value="commercial" type="radio" aria-required="true" id="Address_commercial">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" >Radio Yes
<input name="address_type" value="residential" type="radio" aria-required="true" id="Address_residential">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

The verification function submitPage is called by :

```
<div class="continue"  style="color:blue;">
<input type="submit" class="form-button" value="submit" onclick="submitPage(event)"/>
</div>
```

On the initial page load, is straight forward to verify, but when I return results from an ajax call, the verification is not performed correctly.  Tried adding the $("body").on("click"  but it does not seems to work.

Comment: Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You need to use submit event not click on submit button, otherwise, you will not prevent the submission of the form.

Comment: Thanks, I used this primarily to see if I was getting data from the ajax results.  I was not though.  Not sure if the returned results on "in scope" for the radio buttons, as they are not seen either way.

Comment: They are not seen because probably the form was submitted and the page refreshed. So if you have any console.log they are gone. If you use Google Chrome dev tools you can enable keeping longs between navigations.

Comment: Well not sure if that is correct, on the first iteration (without an ajax update) the alert box pops as it should.  It fails to pop when I have an ajax update applied to the page though.  Which leads me to believe that the returned ajax html results are not in scope for the javascript calls.

Comment: I don't see any AJAX request in your code.

Comment: No, I did not post the ajax call as it is not really relevant, I know it works just fine.  It is the returned results though that are not error checked, which are the two radio buttons.

Comment: "It fails to pop when I have an ajax update applied to the page though." I think that the ajax call is related.